# Working of fork()

Tags: c, linux, fork

I recently learned about the function `fork()` in C. Since this function creates two concurrent processes and these two processes share the memory. So I have the following code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int pid,i;
  i=0;
  pid=fork();
  if(pid==0)
    {
      i++;
      printf("child process:: address of i:%u value of i:%d\n",(int)&i,i);
    }
  else if(pid>0)
    {
      wait(NULL);
      i--;
      printf("parent process:: address of i:%u value of i:%d\n",(int)&i,i);
    }

  return 0;
}
```

The output I am getting is:

```
    child process:: address of i:3215563096 value of i:1
    parent process:: address of i:3215563096 value of i:-1
```

but since every time child is executing first so the value at memory location 3215563096 should become +1 which is on contrast 0 for the parent process.

My expected output is:

```
    child process:: address of i:3215563096 value of i:1
    parent process:: address of i:3215563096 value of i:0
```

Can someone please tell me where I am wrong?

Comment: Is there any method to get my desired result?

Comment: Use shared memory. Look into `mmap`, `shm_open`, etc.

Comment: Sory for the nitpicking, but `fork` is not a *C* function (nor it is in the *C* language standard) but a *Posix* standard function (actually, a system call on Linux).

Comment: Don't forget to use `#include <unistd.h>` to declare `fork()` and `#include <sys/wait.h>` to declare `wait()`; you should not be compiling without prototypes in scope for all functions.

Answer (score 5):

The second process does use the same memory as the original when using *fork*; however, the memory is marked as copy-on-write which means that as soon as the child tries to modify it the memory management in the OS will make a copy of the page so the original process will not see the modified memory. See more at [fork wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_%28operating_system%29).

Answer (score 3):

The child and the parent have different *address spaces*. The virtual memory addresses (which you are printing) **are the same**. But these addresses refer to different physical memory areas.

It's like two people living on "*1st Street*" in different cities.

The advantage of this scheme is that  each process has a different view of the memory - memory protection and separation are inherent.

---

Side note: use `%p` instead of `%u` when printing addresses.

Comment: Is there any way to get my desired output?

Comment: @Piyush: You could map some shared memory, and store a pointer to the shared memory.  The two processes would share the shared memory (hence the name) and would see each other's changes.  See [`shmat()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/shmat.html) et al, or [`shm_open()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/shm_open.html) et al, or [`mmap()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mmap.html) with the right options.

Answer (score 2):

When you fork(), the child process gets an exact **copy** of the parent process' memory. They do not *share* memory.

The address of your variable *i* is the same because they refer to different address spaces - one for the parent, one for the child.

You may be thinking of threads. Threads share memory.

Answer (score 1):

fork()  creates  a new process by duplicating the calling process.  The new process, referred to as the child, is an  exact  duplicate  of  the calling  process.

**The entire virtual address space of  the  parent  is replicated  in the child**.

This is the reason You get same address printed by printf() but physically they are present in different location.

**NOTE**

Remember when ever we use address of operator(&) we get the virtual address only(which is a relative with respect to your process only). The physical address are only managed by memory manager of   your operating system(a primary service of your os).

for more information use command in your linux shell

```
man 2 fork
```